# Disable Results Autosave of Tasks in Prefect

Tags: prefect

Task results are automatically saved under **.prefect/results** folder, which fills the disk in no time.
I need to change this directory globally or disable auto-save.

I set below environment variable but it did not work.

```sh
PREFECT__FLOWS__CHECKPOINTING=false
```

Answer (score 0):

That environment variable is set to True by Prefect Cloud. You need to explicitly do it per task with

```
@task(checkpointing=False)
```

These files are important when restarting Failed flow runs though, so disabling this means data can't just be loaded in during Flow restart. One approach is to always provide the same filenames for Results so that you just keep overwriting the latest Result.

Comment: I did not know that I need to add environment variables to linux unit file(aka .service). Maybe that is why **PREFECT__FLOWS__CHECKPOINTING=false** did not work.
I solved my case problem by mounting a big drive to `~/.prefect` for know. 
Looking forward to tinkering things with task arguments.